# CFWheels DbMigrate

Tags: coldfusion, dbmigrate, cfwheels

I'm following the process here:

http://cfwheels.org/screencasts/view/1

I put the zip file in my localhost/wheelstest/plugins folder. I get

**Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface wheelstest.plugins.cfwheels.cfwheels.**

Running apache with XAMPP under Windows 7. localhost/wheelstest gives me the "Congratulations" page if the DbMigrate zip file is NOT in plugins.

Comment: Which version of wheels? DMigrate doesn't work with 1.3x I think

Comment: It's 1.3.1, so maybe that's it.